# APIs for adding multiple patterns with context to regex

Tags: regex, pcre

I am looking for a regex library which supports APIs to add multiple expressions
(in *steps*), with **context** for each; the **context** [opaque] should be returned while using
the matcher (so that I know which expression matched). For example:

```
re_t re;
int context = 1;
...
reg_add(re, "a{5}b", &context);
...
context = 2;
reg_add(re, "x(p|q)y", &context);
...
reg_match(re, mystring_subject, &context, &begin, &end); // <-- context returned among other info
```

I looked at Regex9(plan9), Onig and PCRE, but I don't see such APIs being present
PCRE has a *callout* facility, but this has to be added to each expression being
compiled, and has a limit of 255. Does anyone know of any open domain regex library
which supports this type of APIs, or any easy-to-modify lib to support this?

P.S. I am looking for a C based lib.

Comment: Seems to me that what you want is a lexer. They do exactly what you want.

Comment: @Dervall, No, I understand the difference between a lexer and a regex. I really want a regex (+ user context)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for a way to use multiple regular expressions to search through a string at the same time, and identify which of your regexes actually found the match.

One solution that works with any regex library is to string all your regexes together using alternation, and to use (named) capturing groups to determine which regex matched.  In your example, you could combine your regexes into `(?<context1>a{5}|b)|(?<context2>x(p|q)y)`.  When this regex finds a match, the matched text will be stored either in the capturing group `context1` or in the capturing group `context2`.

If you prefer to keep the regexes separate, another solution is to iterate over your list of regexes, calling the `match()` function for each of them, and then seeing which one finds the leftmost match.  I have an article on my website about [matching programming language constructs](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examplesprogrammer.html) that explains this technique in more detail.  This works with any regex library that allows you to retrieve match positions (most do).

Comment: yes, that is what I am looking for. But I'm not sure if I made my question clear on **context**, I want to save an _opaque_ context (say, a C `int` value, or a pointer), which,  not only helps me identify which part of the regex matched, but, can also be used in my code. But, isn't stringing together (or to mimic that behavior) faster than iterating over multiple regexes? . Thanks.

Comment: No regex engine that I know allows you to pass arbitrary context to the regex engine.  Store your context into a hash table (if using named capture) or an array (if using numbered capture) and reference that using the name or number of the capturing group that found the match.

Comment: Using one giant regex will be faster, as long as you're not running into any limitations of your regex engine.  E.g. some will only allow 99 capturing groups.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this "context" logic is part of any regex library, but you could program it yourself.  You would store each of your regexes in a map (dictionary) as a key, and the corresponding value would be the "context" for that particular regex.  Then, when you match an input string, iterate over all the entries of the map, and if you find a match, return the corresponding "context" value.  This could be encapsulated into a module or class and provide the API you are looking for.

Comment: Hmm.. that may not work, what is returned on a match is mostly the part of the subject that matched, and not the part of the regex which found it. For example, if my composite regex (after multiple adds, were `^(a{5}b)|(x(p|q)y)$`, on a match, I want to know if `a{5}b` part matched, or `x(p|q)y`

Comment: I would suggest not putting all the regexes into a single one, separated by `...|...|...`, but to keep them separate in a list and try one after the other.  A regex library also allows you to define "match groups" inside your regex (enclosing them in parentheses), but in your scenario a list of independent regexes would actually be more straightforward I think.

Comment: That wont be the same! If I give multiple regexes with alternation, then the regex engine can compile it into a more compact form (in some internal representation - [ND]FA etc) and do a parallel match - AFAIK.

Comment: It is true that putting everything into one regex is more efficient than trying one regex after the other, but the performance difference is likely very small in practice.  No regex engine that I know of would parallelize the matching though.  The reason I suggested separate regexes is that this way, you can more easily attach your opaque context to them and return it upon a match.